# How to get phpstan to infer the type for my Laravel Collection pipeline?

Tags: php, laravel, illuminate-container, phpstan

Given my class

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use stdClass;

class PhpstanIssue
{
    /**
     * @param Collection<Collection<stdClass>> $collection
     *
     * @return Collection<Foo>
     */
    public function whyDoesThisFail(Collection $collection): Collection
    {
        return $collection
            ->flatten() // Collection<stdClass>
            ->map(static function (\stdClass $std): ?Foo {
                return Foo::get($std);
            }) // should now be Collection<?Foo>
            ->filter(); // should now be Collection<Foo>
    }
}
```

I am highely confused why phpstan (0.12.64) would fail with:

```
18: [ERROR] Method PhpstanIssue::whyDoesThisFail() should return
Illuminate\Support\Collection&iterable<Foo> but returns 
Illuminate\Support\Collection&iterable<Illuminate\Support\Collection&iterable<stdClass>>. (phpstan)
```

Why can't phpstan infer the proper result type of this pipe? How can I make phpstan understand the pipe?

---

I can verify that my code works within a phpunit testcase:

```
class MyCodeWorks extends TestCase
{
    public function testPipeline()
    {
        $result = (new PhpstanIssue())->whyDoesThisFail(
            new Collection(
                [
                    new Collection([new \stdClass(), new \stdClass()]),
                    new Collection([new \stdClass()]),
                ]
            )
        );

        self::assertCount(3, $result);
        foreach ($result as $item) {
            self::assertInstanceOf(Foo::class, $item);
        }
    }
}
```

will pass.

---

My `Foo` is just a dummy class for the sake of this question. It's only relevant that it takes a `stdClass` instance and transforms it into a `?Foo` one.

```php
class Foo
{
    public static function get(\stdClass $std): ?Foo
    {
        // @phpstan-ignore-next-line
        return (bool) $std ? new static() : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Illuminate\Support\Collection` is not a generic class by default. Are you also using Larastan?

Comment: @CanVural No, I am currently not using Larastan. Could it be achieved by using it?

Comment: Yes, Larastan has stub files that marks the `Collection` class as generic. It should work with your example. Although it also needs a key type. So something like `Collection<int, Collection<int, stdClass>>`

But if you don't want to use it, you can also just create your stub files that adds the generic PHPDocs to the `Collection` class.

Comment: @CanVural I'd accept that as an answer for upvote / approve btw :)

Comment: @CanVural Bonus points for explicating how to create stub files ;) I never did that before.

Comment: I added an answer.  How to register that stub file with PHPStan is explained in the docs (which I linked in answer), so I didn't repeat it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Illuminate\Support\Collection` class is not generic on its own. So writing `Collection<Foo>` is wrong. That causes the error messages like `Illuminate\Support\Collection&iterable<Illuminate\Support\Collection&iterable<stdClass>>`

You have two options:

1. Installing [Larastan](https://github.com/nunomaduro/larastan/). It's a PHPStan extension for Laravel. And it has [stub files](https://github.com/nunomaduro/larastan/blob/master/stubs/Collection.stub) that makes `Illuminate\Support\Collection` class generic.
2. Or if you are just using the `illuminate/collections` standalone package without full Laravel app you can write your own stub files.
   From [PHPStan docs](https://phpstan.org/user-guide/stub-files):

> ... you can write a stub file with the right PHPDoc. It’s like source code, but PHPStan only reads PHPDocs from it. So the namespace and class/interface/trait/method/function names must match with the original source you’re describing. But method bodies can stay empty, PHPStan is only interested in the PHPDocs.

For your example the following stub file should be enough:

```php
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Support;

/**
 * @template TKey
 * @template TValue
 * @implements \ArrayAccess<TKey, TValue>
 * @implements Enumerable<TKey, TValue>
 */
class Collection implements \ArrayAccess, Enumerable
{
    /**
     * @template TReturn
     * @param callable(TValue, TKey): TReturn $callable
     * @return static<TKey, TReturn>
     */
    public function map($callable) {}
}
```